# Angularjs/Jquery data()

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How to attach arbitrary data to an html element declaratively, and retrieve it.

Please see the code. http://plnkr.co/edit/sePv7Y?p=preview

Angular has the jQuery data() [support](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element).

So, I want to attach data to each `li` element (say _data = node ) in the template, and later on to retrieve it using

```
var li = elm[0]....
console.log('li-', li.data('_data'))
li - {id:1}
```

Code:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('Directives', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.data = [
                    {id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}

        ];
});


app.directive('test', function ($timeout) {
  return {
      template: '<li class="ch" ng-repeat="node in data">' +
                '<span class="span2">' + 'id - {{node.id}}' + '</span>' +
                '</li>',
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
                console.log(elm[0].children);
            }
    };
});
```

### Edit:

Updated the code with how I like to set data.

```
 template: '<li class="ch" ng-repeat="node in data"  data-node="node">' +
```

couldn't select the li element properly now to see whether it is working
tried,

```
elm[0].children[0].data()
elm.children[0].data()
etc..
```

Comment: You code doesn't have anything to do with `data();` so is it safe to assume you haven't tried anything yet?

Comment: I tried, but not sure what is the syntax of setting data declaratively. I just saw a section in jquery doc about html5 data attribute and jquery pulls it in. I am trying to work it out

Comment: Have you got jQuery included?

Comment: no, but angular supports data() through its own implementation jqLite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if it were some third party lib that you are trying to integrate with angular, that *might* be ok, but now you're generating DOM with angular and embedding data in the DOM. This is very strange.

Second, your `test` directive template uses `ngRepeat`, which creates isolate scope and you won't be able to access `li` items declaratively. You will have to use DOM traversal, which is also not very *angular-way-ish*.

Third, your view should be bound to model by angulars two-way bindings. Do not try to simulate opposite behaviour on top of that. Either you should not use angular or you should change your approach to your problem, because it will be pain to develop and maintain otherwise.

I would provide a real answer if you could describe what are you trying to achieve and why exactly do you need that model in `data`. Now the easiest solution would be ditching `test` directive and rewriting it as such:

controller's template:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="node in data" model-in-data="node">
    <span class="span2">id - {{node.id}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

directive `modelInData`

```
.directive('modelInData', function($parse) {
   return {
     restrict: 'A',
     link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
       var model = $parse($attrs.modelInData)($scope);
       $attrs.$set('data', model);
     }
   }
});
```

Here each `li` element adds it's model to the `data` attribute.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer and explanation. You are right, I was trying to incorporate a 3rd party drag and drop plugin, and needed a way to attach some data to the dom element. This is to track where it came from, etc. I will look into your code. thanks again

Comment: While it is not easy to work with drag and drop libraries, such as jQuery's draggable, sortable etc., it's certainly possible to write more or less every interaction declaratively. Just keep in mind that your model should have defined those interactive properties (position, index, list parent, etc). Any action or callback from third party library should update angular's model, (not the DOM!) and then the view should be rerendered by angular according to updates.